# iOS app crash - NSURLConnection+MPIntercept.m

Tags: ios, crash, nsurlconnection, exc-bad-access, crashlytics

I'm struggling to debug a crash that's being reported repeatedly in Crashlytics. Here is a screenshot of the report. Seems that it's caused by Google Analytics (reporting the crash on the GAIThread) but not sure what steps I need to take to address this? I've been unable to reproduce the issue and not even sure what is triggering this.

Has anyone else had experience with EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE caused by GA or similar?

[image]

Comment: Here is the stack trace for more detail https://pastebin.com/AHKEdDQE

Answer (score 2):

Former Crashlytics SDK maintainer here. Information might be stale - best to check in with them for latest information.

The crashtlyics SDK protects itself from infinite recursion (which can produce hundreds of thousands of frames) by truncating repeated frames after a certain threshold. To me, it looks like that's exactly what happened here. The crash occurred in a random function that just happened to be running when the stack overflowed.

What I would do is, first, make sure you have the latest version of this Google SDK. I then might check in with them to see if they know of any reason why that function might recurse. Or, perhaps some documentation covers those conditions and/or options that might affect it's behavior.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Turns out the crash was caused by a separate third party library, mPulse. I believe it attempts to intercept network calls for reporting purposes and so it was trying to latch onto the GA network call, hence why we see references to Google Analytics.

Comment: Makes sense - I'm glad you figured it out!